# Filling out select control with python mechanize

Tags: python-2.7, mechanize

I'm trying to fill out the registration for a website with python mechanize. Everything is going well but I can't figure out how to do the select controls. For example, if I'm picking my birthday month, here's the form that I need to fill out:

```
 <SelectControl(mm=[*, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12])>
```

I've viewed all the answers on stackoverflow already and they all seem to be some variation like this:

```
 br.find_control(name="mm").value = ["0"]
```

or

```
 form["mm"] = ["1"]
```

The problem here is that it gives me a error ItemNotFoundError: insufficient items with name '0'

Comment: Without context is is difficult to help you. Of course `br` resp. `form` need to be right parents to the control. If there are multiple forms on the page, you might be searching in the wrong haystack.

Comment: Say the form is right (there's only 1 form on the page). And here is how I have been filling out the text boxes: br.form['firstname'] = "Name"

Answer (score 1):

```
item = br.find_control(name="mm" type="select").get("12")
item.selected = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Nvm I just needed to do br.form['mm'] = ["1"] <--- I selected this but could have picked any of the values they allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I have used all of the following:

```
br['mm'] = ['9']
br['mm'] = ['9',]
br.form['mm'] = ['9']
br.form['mm'] = ['9',]
```

I seem to remember one case where the comma was mandatory.